# Submit a storm multi-node topology

Tags: java, bigdata, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I would execute the topology of Horton Works, to simulate Trucks Events. 
It work perfectly on a single node (localhost), but now I would use it with multi-nodes.

The event producer works, and I can read the topic without any problem.

But when I run the storm topology, it crashed...

My only modification was in the event_topology.properties :

```
kafka.zookeeper.host.port=10.0.0.24:2181
#Kafka topic to consume.
kafka.topic=vehicleevent
#Location in ZK for the Kafka spout to store state.
kafka.zkRoot=/vehicle_event_spout
#Kafka Spout Executors.
spout.thread.count=1

#hdfs bolt settings
hdfs.path=/vehicle-events
hdfs.url=hdfs://10.0.0.24:8020
hdfs.file.prefix=vehicleEvents
#data will be moved from hdfs to the hive partition
#on the first write after the 5th minute.
hdfs.file.rotation.time.minutes=5

#hbase bolt settings
hbase.persist.all.events=true

#hive settings
hive.metastore.url=thrift://10.0.0.23:9083
hive.staging.table.name=vehicle_events_text_partition
hive.database.name=default
```

After several tries, I test a modification in topology.java :

```
 final Config conf = new Config();
        conf.setDebug(true);
        conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_HOST, "10.0.0.23");
        conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_THRIFT_PORT, 6627);
        conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_PORT, 2181);
        conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS, Arrays.asList("10.0.0.24", "10.0.0.23"));

        //        StormSubmitter.submitTopology(TOPOLOGY_NAME, conf, builder.createTopology());

        final LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();

        cluster.submitTopology(TOPOLOGY_NAME, conf, builder.createTopology());
        Utils.waitForSeconds(10);
        cluster.killTopology(TOPOLOGY_NAME);
        cluster.shutdown();
    }
```

If you have any suggestion, thanks a lot :)

Comment: are you using `LocalCluster.submitTopology` ? In multi node environment you should use `StormSubmitter.submitTopology`

Comment: Hi, finally i used StormSubmitter.submitTopology. But my problem is, that I have Zookeeper in 2 master servers. How can I code that ? Thanks :)

Comment: could you be bit more specific please .. do you  mean you are running with 2 Zk node ? what's the cluster configuration and what exactly you are facing?

Comment: Also what error are you getting? You can check out the Storm UI to see what errors are occurring

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers :)
I found the solution, it was pretty simple...

kafka.zookeeper.host.port=master1:2181,master2:2181

That's all ! Thanks again :)